# SAS macro to list report authorization on user group level

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm looking for a built-in SAS macro that lists each user group along with the LASR reports, which the group is authorized for.

Answer (score 1):

Try `%mduextr`. It will not show their LASR authorization, but it will give a ton of information about which groups they're in and the permissions they have.

`%mduextr(libref=work)`

Another option is `%mdsecds`, which is a security report macro. This gives a lot of information about exactly what folders they have access to. Documentation can be found here:

https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/bicdc/9.4/bisecag/n0l1mpdt430djgn1bl1c3euei85w.htm#p1erksk56y6n0tn1ar0twogmbgz8